# iOS Simulator : Backgrounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, attributes, simulator

In my storyboard I have a Game View Controller, in which I have set a brown background (via the attributes inspector). I have some other view controllers, which also have the same colour bg.

When I run the app in the simulator, my Game View Controller has a grey background (unlike my other two views, which are brown).

As far as I'm aware, the views each have the same properties, so I would imagine that this is something to do with the fact that it is a GAME view controller, and not a normal view controller.

Thanks in advance,

William

Comment: What do you mean Game ViewController? Is that just a subclass of UIViewController that you've called GameViewController? If so then it isn't a specifically separate type of thing, it is just a subclass. Perhaps you need to read up on classes, subclasses and inheritance. Anyway where did you set the backgroundColour of your GameViewController (what method)? Probably be easier for someone to help if you post some code.

Comment: Dear Kristian. 
Thank you for the advice. I'm pretty new to the 'world' of iOS, so please excuse that my lack of information. The Game View Controller was the one and only view that I received as default when I created a new SpriteKit Game. I added my own other view controllers. In the Storyboard editor, I changed the background colour of the attributes panel: the same for my other views which work.

Comment: No worries, we were all new learners at some point. I haven't used spritekit that much yet, but as from what I remember you need to set the backgroundColor property on the SKScene class (called MyScene I think) not the GameViewController. Scenes are layered in front of view controllers so you will see the scene background colour and not the viewControllers background colour. Make sense?

Comment: Dear Kristian, thank you so much for being patient! You were right, my controller was being covered up by the scene so I added in a backgroundColor property to my didMoveToView function, removed the colour in the storyboard, and ran the app. It worked perfectly. Please tell me how to upvote you! Thanks so much, William.

Comment: Happy to help. If you click on a comment you can upvote it (little button to the left). Good luck.

Comment: Not sure I have a high enough reputation :( sorry!

Comment: Don't worry about it